# EXTNET MVC. Use a Store to send data to a page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, extjs, ext.net

I am trying translate a web page dinamically.

The web is done with MVC, and EXTNET framework.

I am using a store in the web. I am trying to load into the X().Store the information of the resources file.

When load the web, the store call an action, who créate an dictionary with the data (key,value).
And then, with a listener, i call a JavaScript function.
But on this JavaScript function, i don't find the array with the values.

The code of the cshtml is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    var X = Html.X();
    @(
    X
    .Store()
    .ID("dsTranslate")
    .AutoLoad(true)
    .Fields(field =>
        {
            field.Add("key");
            field.Add("value");
        }           
    )
    .Listeners(lis=>lis.Load.Fn="TranslateLoaded")
    .Proxy(p =>
        {
            p.Add(
                X.AjaxProxy()
                .Url("/extnet/Translate")
                .Reader(
                        reader => reader.Add(X.JsonReader().RootProperty("data").TotalProperty("total").IDProperty("key"))
                       )
                );
        }
        )
    )
```

The controller code for method /extnet/Translate:

```
public StoreResult Translate()
{

        var lang = "es-ES";

        if (Request.Cookies.Count > 0)
            lang = Request.Cookies["cultureCode"].Value;


        CultureInfo cult = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        try
        {
            cult = new CultureInfo(lang);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }

        ResourceSet res = Resources.ResourceAdministracion.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(cult, true, false);
        IDictionaryEnumerator trav = res.GetEnumerator();
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        while (trav.MoveNext())
        {
            if (trav.Key.ToString().Length > 2)
                dict.Add(trav.Key.ToString(), trav.Value.ToString());
        }

        var q = from c in dict
                select new { key = c.Key, value = c.Value };

        return new StoreResult(q, dict.Count);
    }
```

And where i have the problem. The script js:

```
var TranslateLoaded = function (objGrid, gridRecords, objOptions) {
        for (var i = 0; i < gridRecords.length; i++) {
            alert('Clicked');
        }
}
```

The object gridRecords have only one ítem, but i send 12 or more into the storeresult of the action.

Any idea about the problema with the code? 
Need more parameters into the cshtml?

Debuging the script, i can see the variable total count with the number of records i have, but i don't know where is the array.

I am trying to do like this example:
http://sodeve.net/2011/10/how-to-enable-multi-language-translations-in-ext-net-mvc-part-2/

But it is not in cshtml, and i don't know if all my cshtml code is correct and like the example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

All the previous code is correct.

Only rebuild the Project, and work perfect.

Sorry about the question.